# Draw 2 geom_line() with ggplot

Tags: python, pandas, python-ggplot

Simple.csv:

```
"","teamID","yearID","HR"
"1320","LAN",1958,172
"1325","SFN",1958,170
"1336","LAN",1959,148
"1341","SFN",1959,167
"1352","LAN",1960,126
"1357","SFN",1960,130
"1369","LAN",1961,157
"1375","SFN",1961,183
"1388","LAN",1962,140
"1395","SFN",1962,204
"1408","LAN",1963,110
"1415","SFN",1963,197
"1428","LAN",1964,79
"1435","SFN",1964,165
"1448","LAN",1965,78
```

I'm trying to draw 2 `geom_line()` corresponding to 2 team(`LAN`/`SFN`):

`hr_by_team_year = pandas.read_csv("simple.csv")`

`print ggplot(hr_by_team_year, aes("yearID", "HR", color="teamID")) + geom_point()+ geom_line()`

only to get discrete points:
[image]

But I'm suppose to draw a chart like this:

[image]

according to [Plotting Line Charts](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud359/lessons/692548568/concepts/6785689430923).

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes easier to debug if you specify the name of arguments (even though they are optional).  Suggesting this modification to your code.

```
ggplot(hr_by_team_year, aes(x="yearID", y="HR", color="teamID")) + geom_line()
```

Then, your next concern might have to do with the years on the x-axis.  If your data just has numeric years, the above will probably work.  If it has dates from which you need to display the years, you may need to add something like: `+ scale_x_date(labels='%Y')`

I just did a plot with dates in it where I wanted the x-axis to show dates for every 3 months or so.  This code sample may also help you:

```
ggplot(aes(x='Date', y='Price', color='Daily'), data=googleHiLoPlotData) \
    + geom_line() + scale_x_date(breaks=date_breaks('3 months'), labels='%m-%d-%Y') \
    + ggtitle("Daily Prices of Google")
```

Lastly, while researching how to do this, the following URL helped me:

http://blog.yhat.com/posts/ggplot-for-python.html